# Why do I get a syntax error when I try to print a nested hash that has keys containing colons?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to print an element of a nested data structure:

```
$VAR1 = {
  'SOAP:Body' => {
     'ns1:MT_DF_AssetMaster_Response' => {
       'SUBNUMBER' => {},
       'ASSETCREATED' => {
                         'SUBNUMBER' => {},
                         'ASSET' => {},
                         'COMPANYCODE' => {}
                       },
       'RETURN' => {
                   'PARAMETER' => 'timedependentdata',
                   'MESSAGE_V2' => {},
                   'ID' => 'BAPI1022',
                   'MESSAGE_V1' => 'HW5790',
                   'ROW' => '0',
                   'TYPE' => 'E',
                   'FIELD' => 'plate_no',
                   'LOG_NO' => {},
                   'MESSAGE_V3' => {},
                   'SYSTEM' => 'xxx',
                   'MESSAGE' => 'Invalid date transferred for field xxx:',
                   'MESSAGE_V4' => {},
                   'NUMBER' => '041',
                   'LOG_MSG_NO' => '000000'
                 },
       'xmlns:ns1' => 'urn:ariba.com:xi:OnDemand:Asset',
       'ASSET' => {},
       'COMPANYCODE' => {}
     }
   },
  'xmlns:SOAP' => 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
  'SOAP:Header' => {}
};

print "$data->{SOAP:Body}->{ns1:MT_DF_AssetMaster_Response}->{ASSETCREATED}=>{ASSET}\n";
```

But I get a syntax error:

> syntax error at ./asset_creation.pl line 85, near "{SOAP:"

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which line is line 85

Comment: the print i posted

Comment: try to use: print $data->{"SOAP:Body"}->{"ns1:MT_DF_AssetMaster_Response"}->{"ASSETCREATED"}=>{"ASSET"}."\n";

Comment: tried that but only getting HASH(0x34d66e0) not the exact value which is empty.

Comment: It is right, The value of {"ASSET"} is a hash. What are your expectations?

Comment: i just need to know if the {"ASSET"} is empty, if i try if($asset) it always echo the HASH and not read as empty

Comment: Try this: if (%$asset) ...

Comment: if(%$asset_number) but got this response Can't use string ("HASH(0x1584598)
") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at ./asset_creation.pl line 88.

Comment: What is asset_number?

Comment: solved it already thanks for the help JENS

Comment: Your title is misleading. There are no arrays in your data.

Comment: Please don't edit the word "SOLVED" into your question titles. If you want to indicate that your problem is solved, you can do it by clicking the green checkbox next to the answer that helped you most. If you solve a problem by yourself, you can write your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must write something like this

```
my $asset = $data->{'SOAP:Body'}{'ns1:MT_DF_AssetMaster_Response'}{ASSETCREATED}{ASSET};

print %$asset ? "Asset is NOT empty\n" : "Asset is empty\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

The following are the syntaxes for a hash lookup via reference:

```
REF->{IDENTIFIER}
REF->{EXPR}
```

`ns1:MT_DF_AssetMaster_Response` is neither a valid identifier, nor a valid expression. Replace

```
->{ns1:MT_DF_AssetMaster_Response}
```

with

```
->{'ns1:MT_DF_AssetMaster_Response'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl allows an expression inside the subscripts for an array or a hash. For instance, a variable:

```
$array[ $i ]
```

Or the result of an addition:

```
$array[ $i + $offset ]
```

Or something

```
$array[ cos( $i ) ]
```

It's the same with a hash:

```
$hash{ $key }
```

The dot is still the string concatenation operator:

```
$hash{ $key . $prefix }
```

It's harder to spot when you have barewords smooshed together:

```
$hash{first.last}
```

And in this case, the : is still part of the namespace separator. Perl thinks you aren't done with this expression in the braces so it complains:

```
$hash{ SOAP:Body }   # !!! Error
```

Answer (score -1):

`SOAP:Body` must be quoted: The `:` may not be used without quoting as hash key:

```
print $data->{'SOAP:Body'}->{'ns1:MT_DF_AssetMaster_Response'}
```

You should also remove the `" "` around the variable name in your print statement. The hashref-dereferencing doesn't work otherwise. Your output would be something like

```
HASH(0x123456)->{SOAP:Body}->{ns1:MT_DF_AssetMaster_Response}
```

...but you may still have another error if line 85 isn't the `print` command.

Comment: tried this print $data->{"SOAP:Body"}->{"ns1:MT_DF_AssetMaster_Response"}->{ASSETCREATED}->{ASSET}."\n"; but always getting HASH(0x1f8b6e0) as response.

Comment: *"You should also remove the " " around the variable name in your print statement. The hashref-dereferencing doesn't work otherwise"* That just  isn't true

Comment: @vher: Your `{ASSET}` contains a hash ref, you might want to check `scalar keys %{$data->{"SOAP:Body"}->{"ns1:MT_DF_AssetMaster_Response"}->{ASSETCREATED}->{ASSET‌​}}` which will return the number of keys (0 = no keys).